# Rails Draper Gem raising undefined method for Nested Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, draper

I have various associated model in my application. I have setup Draper to decorate associations upon initialization of the parent class.

I have the following classes:

```
Customer (has_many :accounts)
Account  (belongs_to :customer && has_many :facilities && has_one :contact)
Contact  (belongs_to :account)
Facility (belongs_to :account)
```

I initiate a decorator as follows:

```
@customer = Customer.find_by(:token => params[:token]).decorate
```

In my account_decorator the following is added:

```
decorates_association :contact
decorates_association :facilities
```

...and in my Customer Decorator I have:

```
decorates_association :accounts
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that an undefined method exception is shown for any method defined in the facility_decorator. The contact_decorator works perfectly fine. I have made sure that my AR mapping is right, so it can't be that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe there's an unrelated problem with `Facility` decorator. Have you tried removing the associations and just instantiating decorated `Facility`, just to eliminate that?

Comment: @Ninjarabbi , I have tested instantiating Facility on it's own and using .decorate on it. This does seem to work in this case, as I can access the FacilityDecorator methods

Comment: by the looks of it there's no difference between `contact` and `facility`. It's hard to figure this out without seeing all the code. I'd try to eliminate factors by changing the relation between `account` and `contact` to be `has_many` as well and see if it still works. Then I'd try to replicate parts of code between these two models until I find what makes 'contact` work and `facility` not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by eager_loading the associations.

```
@customer = Customer.eager_load({ :account => [:facilities]}).find_by(:token => params[:token]).decorate
```

This also improved the overall query time, so I'm happy with the solution!